# get google analytics reports in sugarcrm

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, sugarcrm

i need to get the google analytics report on my campaign in my sugarcrm.
i am thinking of creating a new module in my sugar to implement this.
Please tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Sugar partner Epicom has a module for doing this already...

http://www.epicom.com/blog/amandas-blog/custom-google-analytics-module-in-sugarcrm